# How can this problem be solved for integer values?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

\begin{align}
&\max_{p_1,p_2}\,\,\, \log_{2} \left(1+\frac{p_1 h_1}{\sigma}\right)+\log_{2} \left(1+\frac{p_2 h_2}{\sigma}\right)\\
&\text{s.t.}\,\,\, p_1+p_2\leq a
\end{align}

where $h_1, h_2, \sigma$ and $a$ are positive rational constants and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are also positive rationals. I want to ask that how can we optimize $p_1$ and $p_2$ so that

$$\log_2 \left(1+\frac{p_1 h_1}{\sigma}\right)$$

and

$$\log_2 \left(1+\frac{p_2 h_2}{\sigma}\right)$$
are both integer values.